# Inserir no SQL se registro não existir

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

Tenho a seguinte função PHP que adiciona uma linha na tabela:

```
$idmusica = $_GET['idmusica'];
$queryvota=("
    INSERT INTO euk_sugestoes_votos (idusuario, idmusica)
    VALUES ($userid, $idmusica)
    ");
```

A tabela tem essa estrutura:

```
id | idusuario | idmusica
```

Mas queria que antes de inserir, ele verificasse se essa linha com o idusuario e idmusica já existe. Se já existir, deve ignorar, senão ele insere.

Como posso fazer essa verificação?

Obrigado!

Comment: Não sei se é seu caso, mas cuidado se estiver usando mysql_query, pois está obsoleta na versão atual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem sim, crie um `index unique` para as 2 colunas `id_usuario` e `idmusica` e ao invés de utilizar `INSERT INTO` utilize o `REPLACE INTO`, basicamente ele faz essa verificação automática.

O `index unique` já resolveria o problema, porém iria retornar um erro.

E trocando para `REPLACE` como não vai atualizar nenhum campo, ele apenas vai ignorar o registro.

Porém o `REPLACE` vai alterar sua chave primária, caso seja `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Outra maneira, também mantendo um `index unique` é usar o `INSERR IGNORE`, ai ficaria dessa maneira, por exemplo:

`INSERT IGNORE INTO euk_sugestoes_votos(idusuario,idmusica)VALUES(1,2);`

Para criar o index, segue comando:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_unique_idusuario_idmusica
    ON euk_sugestoes_votos (idusuario,idmusica);
```

Comment: mas com o index unique ele não vai permitir ter 2 registro iguais certo? é que preciso ter por exemplo: idusuario=1 e idmusica=2; idusuario=1 e idmusica=1; idusuario=2 e idmusica=2...etc

Comment: Exatamente, ele nunca vai deixar repetir os dois juntos idusuario e idmusica. não separados, você pode ter n idusuario(1) e n idmusica(1) porém nunca repetidos

Comment: pergunta básica, como crio o index unique pros 2?

Comment: @LeandroMarzullo editei a resposta com o script de criação do index

Comment: SHOW! Deu certinho, valeu!

Comment: Boa @LeandroMarzullo por nada! ;)